# No boot device found

Tags: boot, hard-drive

I have a Dell Inspiron 15 3567, and my 1TB Hard Drive looks like this:
500gb - windows
500gb - ubuntu.
All good, but this morning when i opend it, my boot return this error: No boot device found, press any key to reboot.
I thought it is broken, but i installed an ubuntu on an USB and run it on the laptop without installation. In "Disks" application, it shows me the HDD and says it is good.
[see screen shot from Disks here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cORQC.png)

Could anyone help me?

Comment: Have you tried `boot-repair`?

Comment: here's a link to show you how to use boot-repair. https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows

Answer (score 0):

Use boot-repair.  I had the same issue just the other day.  I've been running a stable Ubuntu system for several weeks.  I shut it down and everything seemed normal.  Next day I attempted to boot and got the same message you did, "No boot device found.  Press any key to reboot."  I figured my hard drive died.  Actually it was just a boot issue that was fixed using boot-repair.  I booted to my live Ubuntu on USB stick.  I opened a terminal and entered the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install boot-repair
boot-repair
```

After running boot-repair everything was back to normal.  I still have no idea what happened to cause the problem, but since it was relatively easy to fix I'm not seriously concerned.

Note: Boot-repair appeared to freeze during the actual process of resetting GRUB and several error messages appeared in my terminal window regarding boot-repair.  Eventually boot-repair completed it's work and gave a report that included errors.  And then I rebooted my system and it worked like a charm.